# Export .xls from VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone help me with a way to export a .xls file to a specific folder with the data I have in the current excel?

More specific: I have a function that fills some cells in the excel file. But I would like to export that data into a separate file, not into the one where I am currently working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs path & "\filename"
```